# How to enable token authentication in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I am running Juypter Notebook version 6.0.0 on a remote server. There is password authentication in place and according to the docs if this is so then token authentication is disabled. However I need to enable token authentication so I can set up Google Colab(which requires token based authentication) with a local runtime on the remote server. While there are several links describing how to disable authentication, I couldn't find any on how to enable it.

The output of `jupyter notebook list` does not show any tokens. Even resetting the password does not generate a token.

Comment: Did you disable manually token-based authentication in the past or your provider disabled it as a feature (apparently)?

Comment: I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your notebook provider has disabled tokens. In this [doc](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html) the steps to disable token is given, so I applied exactly opposite steps and it worked. Since you have a remote server, if you somehow manage to restart jupyter notebook remotely, then you can do the same.

Steps:

- Edit the config file, jupyter_notebook_config.json
- Add this line to the config, as in the picture

  `"token": "YOUR_TOKEN",`
- You can use token consisting of hex characters (0-9, a-f) as a token
- Remove the line that contains password
- Now you need to restart the server
- Exit by clicking 'Quit'
- After you log back next time, give the token instead

[image: editing config file]

Location of config file:

```
Windows: "C:\Users\Username\.jupyter\"

Linux: "/home/user/.jupyter"
```

Comment: There is no display of any token

Comment: I see. Your server has disabled tokens. Due to the fact that you need a local notebook instance to connect to Colab, even if you somehow enable the use of tokens on the remote server, you still would'nt be able to connect. Btw, what service are you using to host notebooks?